# Calling an ElementMethod in a DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, styles, datatrigger

I have a TextBox thats using this Style. I need to add a Focus() method to in this style.
So that when the TextBox is Visible and the ValidParent Property is false then i call the Focus() method on that TextBox

```
<Style x:Key="ParentTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ValidParent }" Value="false">
            ...
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ValidParent }" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is this possible ?? And if it is then if i had multiple textboxes with the same behaviour which one will recieve Focus?? Does the Order of the Controls in my Xaml make a diffrence then ??
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call methods via style triggers. Using `Interactivity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22829) you have more options, including method calls but they cannot be easily used in styles.